# Filiter Data by get the first day of the month in Excel

Tags: excel

This command line gives the last work day of the month (True or False). I don't know how to change the commands to get the first work day of each month. If we are assuming the entire column A is the Date. format is mm/dd/year

AND(WEEKDAY(A2,2)<6,MONTH(WORKDAY(A2,1))<>MONTH(A2))

Comment: But January 1st is the first working day in 2004 or do you include holidays?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first day of the month is

```
date-DAY(date)+1
```

In your case:

```
A2-DAY(A2)+1
```

To check weather A2 is the first day of its month:

```
A2 = A2-Day(A2)+1
'Simplify equation
Day(A2) = 1
```

So as a result `=(Day(A2)=1)` evaluates to `True/False`

Regarding your formula weather a date is the last day of the month, that can be done by:

```
=(A2=EOMONTH(A2,0)
```

Comment: Is there any way to make a bit more flexible?   
For example, The February second is the first day of the month in this data set?     I think it involves some workday situation.     How do you make that return true?

Comment: What do you mean by more flexible?

Comment: Can you add this to the question, so it is a little better formatted?

Comment: Wait are you looking for the first WORKDAY or the first day of the month? The first day is the 1th of Febuary the first Workday is the first Monday in Febuary

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is what you're looking for

```
=DAY(A2)=1
```